# convert image to base64 and check size

Tags: c#, base64, filestream

I am using the following c# code to convert an image file to a base64 string

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            var buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
            fs.Read(buffer, 0, (int)fs.Length);
            var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
        }
```

How can I test the before and after size? ie. the image file size and the size of the base 64 string. I want to check if I am winning or losing by using converting it.

Comment: For reading into the buffer, try `var buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can calculate it by using simple math. One character of base64 represents 6 bits, and therefore four characters represent three bytes. So you get 3/4 bytes per character. Which gives:

```
int base64EncodedSize = 4 * originalSizeInBytes / 3;
```

Depending on how the data is padded it might be off by a character or two but that shouldn't make a difference.

Also, if you suspect base64 might be *more* efficient, what on earth are you comparing it with? Compared to raw binary, it always causes a 33% increase in size.

Comment: Actually a 167% increase, since `Convert.ToBase64String` returns a unicode string.

Comment: @MusiGenesis: ...which, when encoded using a proper transport encoding (UTF-8), doesn't take any more space than a latin-1 string, for instance.

Comment: True, but *while* it's still a .Net string it's twice as big. I'm not sure what this person is trying to accomplish, but you're right that they're presumably sending this somewhere, and not keeping it in-memory or writing it into a DB text field or something.

Answer (score 0):

You're losing - the base64 string will use more bytes to store than would your original image.  Possibly a *lot* more, if this is all in-memory:  strings in .Net are unicode, so they use twice as many bytes as an ASCII-encoded string would.